# What does the word "cinemaddict" mean?

Tags: meaning, nouns, synonyms, neologisms

Please explain to me (non-native speaker) what the word "cinemaddict" means. What synonyms does it have?

Comment: Where have you heard this?

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-11066046 <-this

Comment: Referenced in Bill Bryson's book "One Summer" as a squashed neologism of the 1920's coined in Time magazine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Film buff" is fairly common term for a person who is a fan of cinema.  A few years ago there was a documentary [Cinemania](http://uk.imdb.com/title/tt0281724/), but I've never heard the terms cinemaddict or cinemanic.

Comment: Film buff - bingo! excellent!

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like a [portmanteau word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/portmanteau+word) created from "cinema" and "addict", but I've never heard it used before.

Comment: and presumably therefore means someone who is addicted to the cinema.

Comment: The curse of the portmanteau has arrived on this site too. Soon every article here will be edited to include the word "portmanteau" and a link to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @JohnFx: a bunch of insane gnomes on Wikipedia add the word "portmanteau" in every possible place they can, for some reason, and cling onto the addition for grim death, adding the articles with "portmanteau" to their "watchlist" so that they can instantly restore the word if anyone tries to remove or change it. This is quite well-known on Wikipedia. For example, look at [the talk page on the "portmanteau" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Portmanteau#The_ubiquity_of_portmanteau). The most surprising thing about it is that linguists don't even use this word; they use the word "blend".

Comment: Portmanteau is, however, a perfectly cromulent word for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

"Cinemaddict" sounds like it is a kind of pun made from "cinematic" and "addict".

Comment: In its current form, this is really the only possible answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it refers to a person who commonly visits the cinema to watch movies (a cinema addict).

As far as I am aware, it is not an actual word and is likely something used occasionally by people in a colloquial context. However, I can't find much supporting evidence around the net for this assumption.

**Edit:** as requested, another term which essentially means the same thing might be '[movie-goer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moviegoer)' (person who visits the movies). Having said that, I think the exact word you might use could change depending on the context.

**Edit 2:** asking for a domain name is probably another question in itself, and it's such an open-ended question I'm not sure how much I can necessarily help you. Perhaps some kind of variation depending on the person's name?

- JoeWatchesMovies.com
- ThoughtsOnFilms.com / ThoughtsOnMovies.com

I haven't checked whether those (or any like it) are available though. I'm sure others might be able to offer more (and better) suggestions, but its a little outside the topic of this site really.

Comment: could you suggest any synonyms? I need o word like this, which means the person - movie critit, honest critis, movie watcher etc.

Comment: I'm looking for a nice domain's name for a personal blog of movie critic. Could you suggest me something?

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is addicted to cinemas (or movies)