# Is ‘Yes-ish’ a perfect alternative to Yes, or is it 'Yes ‘on condition’? Is it received English?

Tags: meaning, formality, suffixes, is-it-a-word

I found a word ‘Yes-ish’ in the answer (from PLL) to my question about the meaning of ‘Stuck to the script’ I posted today.  As it is quite new to my ear, I consulted with Wikipedia before logging out the forum, which says:
 (Yesih) is yes with a condition or limitation, and similarly Noish (but this of course tends more to a ....

Is ‘Yes-sh / Yessh’ often heard in day-to-day conversation among American people or found in casual writings.
How ‘Yes-sh’ is different from ‘Yes’ in its implication, supposing it’s an informal or colloquial expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'ish' is added to some words to denote 'sort of'. For example:

> He was tall-ish

Means he was tall, but not extremely so. Taller than average, but not basketball-player tall.

> I'm tired-ish

Means you're a little tired but not totally 'knackered' (a bit of British slang there).

Generally '-ish' is considered informal; slightly slang-ish!

You perhaps wouldn't use it in formal situations like a business meeting. It's not considered *rude*, it's just something you'd use in more relaxed settings.

This reminds me of a joke by a British comedian called Jimmy Carr

> Catholics have a confirmation where someone says, "You are definitely Catholic". Jews are never sure: they say "Well, I'm Jew-ish".

Here the comedian has made a 'play on words' and used the 'sort of' meaning of -ish as opposed to that seen in Jewish, English etc.

Comment: That was Jonathan Miller's line in Beyond the Fringe: "I'm not really a Jew: just Jew-ish, not the whole hog"

Answer (score 6):

The definition for *-ish* is

> -ish
>   suffix forming adjectives:
>   1. (from nouns) having the qualities or characteristics of: *apish*, *girlish*.
>   • of nationality or religious or ethnic group: *Swedish* , *Amish*, Flemish.
>   2. (from adjectives) somewhat: *yellowish*.
>   • informal denoting an approximate age or time of day: *sixish*.

I think that *yes-ish* can be understood as *somewhat yes*, even *yes* is not an adjective and *-ish* is not used to form an adjective.

Comment: So Yessh means 'I feel like saying 'Yes,' 'I can (tend to) agree with you,' though it's not 120% approval of the other's proposition?

Comment: It means that is not a 100% _yes_, but it's not a _no_ either. For how I understand it, it's closer to _yes_ than to _no_.

Comment: Ish in this use means "sort of". So yes-ish might mean someting like "yes, but not completely" or "yes, but not exactly".

Comment: This reminds me of the German [*jein*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jein), a — [dare I say it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/what-does-word-cinemaddict-mean/1856#1856) — [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of *ja* (yes) + *nein* (no), though it's kind of 50/50.

Comment: We have _nì_, in Italian, which is a mix between _no_ (_no_) and _sì_ (_yes_).

Comment: And the Brit-ish have the knights that say NI!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I have ever heard the term "Yes-ish" in actual conversation, and I've certainly never read it. That being said, as a native (American) English speaker, I would know what someone meant if they said "Yes-ish".

"-ish" can be added intelligibly to a number of words (primarily adjectives), but it is not generally done. When I choose to use "-ish" in conversation, it's generally an attempt at humor. In most cases, you would just use a modifier, e.g., "I am pretty sure" instead of "I am sure-ish".