# Melomaniac but for movies?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word like [melomaniac](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/melomaniac) but for movies or Tv series?

Comment: It’s hard to be a maniac about anything when you’re really mellow... ;-)

Comment: Related:[What does the word cinemaddict mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/what-does-the-word-cinemaddict-mean) One of the answers mentions _cinemaniac_, which is a pretty popular usage on the net.

Comment: @Matas Vaitkevicius, Do you mean 'word for a person who loves *movies and TV shows*? (The question is ambiguous). :/

Comment: A [*filmophile*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=filmophile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Moviemaniac**" is another term meaning "**cinemaniac**" ([ref.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=moviemaniac)).

There is also "**filmaholic**" and "**movieholic**" ([ref.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/filmaholic)), but according to the Wiktionary, despite the disaproving "aholic" appending  connoting "addiction" those two terms connote rather the idea of  enthusiasm  (cinephile ([ref.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cinephile)), cineast) and not that  of addiction. This is in contradiction with [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=filmaholic) and it seems that the usual meaning of this form (aholic) should be preserved.

However, when it comes to TV the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TVaholic) falls in line with the usual sense of "aholic" and lets us know that there is "**TVaholic**", rarely found and connoting addiction to TV watching.